# LINQ: order results of join based on inner collection

Tags: linq, sql-order-by

Is it possible to order the results of a LINQ join operation based on the inner collection order?

Say I have two collections:

```
var names = new[]{"John", "Mary", "David"};
var persons= new[]{ new Person{Name="John", Title"Prof"}, new Person{Name="Mary", Title="Accountant"}, new Person{Name="David", Title="Mechanic"}, new Person{Name="Peter", Title="Homeless"}}
```

if I do a LINQ join to get a subset of persons as follows:

```
var taxPayers =
                persons
                    .Join(names , p => p.Name, n => n, (p, n) => p)
                    .Select(f => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(f.Name, f.Title));
```

The result is ordered based on the persons array.

It is possible using LINQ, to order taxPayers based on the order of names?  Or is this not a LINQable operation?

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply reversing the join should work. Instead of joining names to persons, join persons to names.

Comment: Thanks for response.  Reversing the join returns a collection of names instead of a collection of persons, which I what I need.

Comment: @e28Makaveli, if so, you are not reversing enough. That is to say, if you leave `(p, n) => p` unchanged, you will experience the failure you mention. However, if you instead had `(n, p) => p` to reflect that your name (n) is first, person (p) is second, and you want the second, then you should be fine.

Comment: @drharris, it would be beneficial to provide a code sample to make your answer complete. It has obviously led to confusion.

Comment: @ Anthony Pegram, that was it, thanks.  I had (n, p) => n instead of what you suggested.  Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, left for a quick meeting... Thanks @Anthony for clarifying all parts of the reversal!